# Why do I have to store the result of a function in a variable?

Tags: kotlin

Is it because some functions will change the object and some don't so you have to store the returned value in a variable? I'm sure there's a better way to ask the question, but I hope that makes sense.

Example case: Why doesn't `thisString` stay capitalized? What happens to the output of the `toUpperCase()` function when I call it on `thisString`? Is there a name for this behavior?

```
var thisString: String = "this string"
var thatString: String = "that string"

thisString.toUpperCase()
thatString = thatString.toUpperCase()

println(thisString)
println(thatString)
```

which prints:

```
this string
THAT STRING
```

Comment: Strings in Kotlin are immutable. That's just how they decided to do it

Comment: Ok, so if the data type and variable its store in are mutable, then a function like that will typically change the value of the variable. Right?

Comment: the variable is not a string, it is a reference to a string. `foo = "hello"` means foo references the immutable string "hello". `foo = "world"` and foo now references a different immutable string "world". Foo was modified to reference something else. the strings themselves were not modified. `thatString = thatString.toUpperCase()` takes the first immutable string thatString was referencing, generates a new immutable string, then assigns thatString a reference to that new immutable string.

Comment: Thanks, that's super helpful. Is it also true that `thisString.toUpperCase()` returned `THIS STRING` and its in memory somewhere but because I didn't store it in a variable I have no reference to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By convention if a function starts with the word *to* or a past participle, it always returns a new object and does not mutate the object it's called on. But that's not exclusively true. Functions that begin with a verb may or may not mutate the object, so you have to check the documentation to know for sure.

A mutable object might still have functions that return new objects. You have to check the documentation for the function you call.

For a function that returns a new object, if you don't do anything with the returned result or store it in a variable, it is lost to the garbage collector and you can never retrieve it.

String is an immutable class, so none of the functions you call on it will ever modify the original object. Immutable classes are generally less error-prone to work with because you can't accidentally modify an instance that's still being used somewhere else.

All the primitives are also immutable. If all the properties of a class are read-only `vals` and all the class types they reference are also immutable classes, then the class is immutable.

If you want an mutable alternative to `String`, you can use `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `CharArray`, or `MutableList<Char>`, depending on your needs. They all have different pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't thisString stay capitalized?

Because that's how [the function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-upper-case.html) was coded (emphasis mine):

"Returns **a copy** of this string converted to upper case using the rules of the default locale."

> What happens to the output of the toUpperCase() function when I call it on thisString?

Nothing. If you don't assign it to a variable (save a reference to it) it's discarded.

> Is there a name for this behavior?

AFAIK, this is simply "ignoring the return value".

Hope that helps.